# How to solve this inequality algebraically?

Tags: inequality

|x+3|<-1
 how to solve this algebraically. I can solve it by using graphs. [image]

Comment: Distinguish the cases $x+3\ge 0$ and $x+3<0$

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your given inequality has no solution since $$\vert{x+1\vert}\geq 0$$

Answer (score 3):

An absolute value is non-negative . It can't be $\;<-1$.